# java.lang.ClassCastException when removing components from a JLayeredPane

Tags: swing, classcastexception, event-dispatch-thread, jlayeredpane

I've got a problem and I can't understand why it happens.

I'd like to add to a JLayeredPane another JLayeredPane with some buttons. When one of this button is clicked i wanto to remove to the first JLayeredPane the secondo JLayeredPane.

Here is the method where I try to remove the second JLayeredPane

```
public void clearAsk() throws ClassCastException {
    Component[] components = layeredPane.getComponentsInLayer(2);
    for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++){
        JLayeredPane toClear = (JLayeredPane) components[i];
        toClear.removeAll();
        toClear.validate();
        layeredPane.remove(components[i]);
        layeredPane.validate();
    }
    layeredPane.validate();
    layeredPane.repaint();
}
```

When this method is called the following exception is sometimes (not always) shown.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException
at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getNextFocusCandidate(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.doRestoreFocus(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.restoreFocus(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why does it happen? And why does it not always happen? I really can't find a solution to this problem...

Answer (score 0):

When you're going through all the components in the layer, you're assuming that each component is a `JLayeredPane` when it is quite possible that it is actually something else. Instead, what you can do is safely check whether or not the component is an **instanceof** `JLayeredPane` before removing it:

```
public void clearAsk() throws ClassCastException {
    Component[] components = layeredPane.getComponentsInLayer(2);
    for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++){
        if(components[i] instanceof JLayeredPane) { 
            JLayeredPane toClear = (JLayeredPane) components[i];
            toClear.removeAll();
            toClear.validate();
            layeredPane.remove(components[i]);
            layeredPane.validate();
        }
    }
    layeredPane.validate();
    layeredPane.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this solution doesn't work and the exception is (sometimes) shown. I don't think that's the problem: I am actual sure that components will be an array of (one) jLayeredPane..